# CSS base64 .svg mask in Firefox - change background colour

Tags: html, css, firefox, svg, mask

I have a base64 .svg image as a mask background applied to an element. The user can change the background of the element any colour they wish.

This is my css

```
.tapToSign {
    mask: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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) center center no-repeat;
    -webkit-mask: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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) center center no-repeat;
    -moz-mask: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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) center center no-repeat;
}
```

Then the user can use a colour picker, which changes the background of the element (hence changing the colour of the svg image.)

This works fine in Chrome but doesn't work at all on Firefox.

The original svg content is below.

```
<svg version="1.1" id="CCW" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
 viewBox="0 0 20 20" enable-background="new 0 0 20 20" xml:space="preserve">
    <path d="M0.685,10h2.372V9.795c0.108-4.434,3.724-7.996,8.169-7.996c4.515,0,8.174,3.672,8.174,8.201s-3.659,8.199-8.174,8.199
c-1.898,0-3.645-0.65-5.033-1.738l1.406-1.504c1.016,0.748,2.27,1.193,3.627,1.193c3.386,0,6.131-2.754,6.131-6.15
c0-3.396-2.745-6.15-6.131-6.15c-3.317,0-6.018,2.643-6.125,5.945V10h2.672l-3.494,3.894L0.685,10z"/>
</svg>
```

Could I do something to the svg file itself to allow the colour to be changed, or is this not possible at all on Firefox?

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: The data does not contain a mask element. Firefox only supports mask urls that point to a mask element.

Comment: Do I need to add the mask around it, or create a new one with the mask?

Comment: Adding the mask around it might work. Try it and see. You'll need to adjust the URL so its fragment identifier is the mask id

Comment: So would I just need to base64 the mask part of the .svg, or the whole image with the svg tag? First time using .svg images this way

Comment: The whole image with the SVG tag.

Comment: @Pooshonk did you ever discover if that solution worked? Please post your findings.

Comment: Yes I did. I'll post it tomorrow when I'm back in the office

Answer (score 0):

Firefox now support mask Css property. You can try to use that.

```
.tapToSign {
    mask: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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) center center no-repeat;
    -webkit-mask: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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) center center no-repeat;
}
```